# How do we set/modify the name for a specific dependency defined in pom.xml for a Java project?

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, pom.xml

Right now, the name is set to 'name + version'. I need to exclude the version from the final name.
Eg - For

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>group-a</groupId>
  <artifactId>artifact-b</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I am seeing artifact-b-1.0.jar getting generated in my build, but I want it named artifact-b.jar so that I need need to alter all the scripts using the jar every time the version changes.

Answer (score 1):

During build, your jar is generated to `target`. You can change the name for target using the `finalName` parameter. If you use install, the artifact is installed to the local repository (you cannot influence the name in the local repository). If you do deploy ,the artifact is deployed to a remote repository (there you cannot also *not* influence the name).

Comment: You cannot influence the name with `install:install`, but you can with `install:install-file`; see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58030804/1744774).

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>package.class.main.Method</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
                <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: You miss the plugin name etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`install-file` goal](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/install-file-mojo.html) of the [Maven Install Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/index.html):

```xml
    <groupId>group-a</groupId>
    <artifactId>artifact-b</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>install-file-${project.artifactId}</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>install-file</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <file>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.jar</file>
                            <artifactId>artifact</artifactId>
                            <version>b</version>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

`mvn install` output:

```
[INFO] ...
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ so58011949 ---
[INFO] Building jar: ...\target\so58011949-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:3.0.0-M1:install (default-install) @ artifact-b ---
[INFO] Installing ...\target\artifact-b-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
       to ...\.m2\repository\group-a\artifact-b\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\artifact-b-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] Installing ...\pom.xml
       to ...\.m2\repository\group-a\artifact-b\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\artifact-b-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:3.0.0-M1:install-file (install-file-artifact-b) @ artifact-b ---
[INFO] Installing ...\target\artifact-b-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
       to ...\.m2\repository\group-a\artifact\b\artifact-b.jar
[INFO] Installing ...\AppData\Local\Temp\artifact-b-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT7551062015093608214.pom
       to ...\.m2\repository\group-a\artifact\b\artifact-b.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ...
```

Local repository:

```
|
+- group-a
|  +- artifact
|     +- b
|        +- artifact-b.jar
|        +- artifact-b.pom
|  +- artifact-b
|     +- 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
|        +- artifact-b-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
|        +- artifact-b-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
|
```

Comment: I learned to see things stricter. Many "quick solutions" with Maven backfired at us (later) because some Maven plugin or Eclipse integration or whatever did not work properly. And in this case, I also see such problems: The OP said that he/she wants to strip the version number to avoid changing scripts when new versions arrive. Your hack, when applied to a remote repository like Nexus, will usually fail to deploy the same artifact a second time because the repository only lets you overwrite SNAPSHOT artifacts (not ones with a version `b`).

Comment: I don't know. I was also surprised that it was suddenly gone.